# Add a custom field as a default value in WooCommerce backend and populate previous orders

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields

I know that the first part of my question is possible but haven't found how to add a custom field to **all orders** in the back end and then populate it with a default value.

I'm looking to create a custom field called "Merchant Identifier" and then populate that with a default name e.g "Company X".

I looked at this code which adds an input value at the checkout and then shows in an order summary, but I only need a field adding as a custom field to every order in the back end.

```
/**
 * Process the checkout
 */
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'my_custom_checkout_field_process');

function my_custom_checkout_field_process() {
    // Check if set, if its not set add an error.
    if ( ! $_POST['billing_phone_new'] )
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Phone 2 is compulsory. Please enter a value' ), 'error' );
}


/**
 * Update the order meta with field value
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta' );

function my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_phone_new'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'billing_phone_new', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_phone_new'] ) );
    }
}


/**
 * Display field value on the order edit page
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );

function my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta($order){
    echo '<p><strong>'.__('Phone 2').':</strong> <br/>' . get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), 'billing_phone_new', true ) . '</p>';
}
```

Once that custom field appears on **all new and old orders** I can then add this add this as a column in a scheduled CSV export (that's for later - I just need to achieve the first part).

I'm not sure whether I need to have a hidden field in the checkout first with a default value OR whether I can just add a custom field that shows on all the orders in the back end using a different method.

Anyone able to help?

Thanks

Comment: You could use a custom SQL query or `wc_get_orders` or `WC_Order_Query` to read and update previous orders. In order to give a concrete answer, your question is missing some details to create [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks. Hopefully, there is more of a reproducible example above that is close to what i'm trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For new orders you can use the following

```php
// Update the order meta with value 
function action_woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
    // Meta value
    $meta_value = 'Company X';
    
    update_post_meta( $order_id, 'merchant_identifier', $meta_value );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'action_woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 10, 1 );

// OPTIONAL (will still work without this code, this is just to show it visually)
// Display field value on the order edit page
function action_woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address( $order ) {  
    echo '<p><strong>' . __( 'Merchant Identifier', 'woocommerce') . ':</strong> ' . $order->get_meta( 'merchant_identifier' ) . '</p>';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'action_woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 10, 1 );
```

---

For existing orders you can perform the following function, after it has been executed (view any page - frontend) it may be removed.

```
// Run once, delete afterwards
function set_meta_for_old_orders () {
    // Get ALL orders where meta key not exists
    $orders = wc_get_orders( array(
        'limit'        => -1, // Query all orders
        'meta_key'     => 'merchant_identifier', // Post meta_key
        'meta_compare' => 'NOT EXISTS', // Comparison argument
    ));
    
    if ( ! empty ( $orders ) ) {
        // Meta value
        $meta_value = 'Company X';
        
        foreach ( $orders as $order ) {
            $order->update_meta_data( 'merchant_identifier', $meta_value );
            $order->save();
        }

        echo 'Done!';
    }
}
// Call function
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'set_meta_for_old_orders' );
```

Comment: Many thanks, @7uc1f3r - The existing orders function was fine with a small amount of orders but on a much larger database of orders it didn't work, (there were PHP memory errors) hence your original suggestion that a custom SQL query would be better!

Comment: @MikeDevitt a custom sql query is indeed recommended. Another option is to adjust the limit (now -1) and, for example, to perform this action per 200 orders. 
Know that in addition to accepting the answer, you also have the option to [upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) it. 
Thanks in advance! best regards